# How to return this to parent function in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Hello i have some question , how to return this object to parent function.
Onlick fancybox inner element get fancybox options and changeit.

example

```
        afterShow:function(){

            var fancy = this;

            $('.fancybox-inner a.fullsize').click(function(){

                fancy.maxHeight = 500;

            });

        },
```

i need onclick return this.maxHeight to afterShow function , but its return to click function.

Comment: is it not available as `fancy.maxHeight` after the click function?

Comment: First, you need to use `$(this.element)` to ref to `this` inside any fancybox callback. Second, you cannot `extend` fancybox options once it's already opened. Third, you may rather try to set the `max-height` of the content from within the content itself and then call the `$.fancybox.update()` method to adjust the `height`. I just wonder why would you need this function if there might be another way to do what you want to achieve instead of overcomplicated things.

Comment: but when i remove click function and aftershow contents only            `this.maxHeight = $(window).height();`
`$.fancybox.update();` all works fine , but i need assign this to click...

Answer (score 0):

i solve this with jquery function $.proxy

```
    afterShow:function(){

        $('.fancybox-inner a.fullsize').click($.proxy(function(){

            this.maxHeight += 500;
            $.fancybox.update();

        },this));

    },
```

now its easy chnage launched fancybox options ;)